# Negative lookahead -- At the begining of the string

Tags: ruby, regex, regex-lookarounds

I want to to do string substitutions in Ruby, but only when certain conditions are *not* met.

Replace all occurances of 'allegro4' with 'allegro' when the line doesn't start with an `#include` statement. I tried this but I am not having any success. The substitution is simply not done.

```
"#include <allegro4/allegro4.h>".gsub(/(?!#include) allegro4/, 'allegro')
```

Looking at other example of negative lookaheads and trying different things in `irb` lead me to believe that there is something weird going on with negative lookaheads specifically at the beginning of strings.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

```
R = /
    \A              # match beginning of string
    (?!\#include)   # do not match '#include' at start of string (negative lookahead)
    .*?             # match any number of any character
    <               # match '<'
    \K              # forget everything matched so far
    allegro         # match string
    (\d+)           # match one or more digits in capture group 1
    \/allegro       # match string
    \1              # match the contents of capture group 1
    /x              # Free-spacing regex definition mode

def replace_unless(str)
  str.gsub(R, 'allegro/allegro') 
end

replace_unless "cat #include <allegro4/allegro4.h>"
  #=> "cat #include <allegro/allegro.h>" 
replace_unless "cat #include <allegro4/allegro3.h>"
  #=> "cat #include <allegro4/allegro3.h>"
replace_unless "#include <allegro4/allegro4.h>"
  #=> "#include <allegro4/allegro4.h>"
```

I have assumed that the specific string 'allegro' is to be matched and that any non-negative integer can follow both instances of 'allegro', but one cannot have different numbers following the two instances of 'allegro'. If the number must be `4`, replace both `(\d+)` and `\1` in the regex with `4`. If 'allegro' is merely a stand-in for any string of lower-case letters, the regex can be changed as follows.

```
R = /
    \A              # match beginning of string
    (?!\#include)   # do not match '#include' at start of string (negative lookahead)
    .*              # match any number of any character
    <               # match character
    \K              # forget everything matched so far
    ([[:lower:]]+)  # match one or more lower-case letters in capture group 1
    (\d+)           # match one or more digits in capture group 2
    \/              # match character
    \1              # match the contents of capture group 1
    \2              # match the contents of capture group 2
    /x              # Free-spacing regex definition mode

def replace_unless(str)
  str.gsub(R, '\1/\1') 
end

replace_unless "cat #include <cats9/cats9.h>"
  #=> "cat #include <cats/cats.h>" 
replace_unless "dog #include <dogs4/dogs3.h>"
  #=> "dog #include <dogs4/dogs3.h>" 
replace_unless "#include <pigs4/pigs4.h>"
  #=> "#include <pigs4/pigs4.h>"
```